# Transform js to html

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I want to extract components from a template that I have, those components are generated with javascript & svg.
Is there's a way to convert them to pure html?
So I can manipulate them easily.
I am trying to take only those components to use them in different template.
But I find out I can't do that until I convert all the code to html.
Or maybe there's another way that I am not aware of.
Thank you.

This one is included in the html file besides the js file

```
  <script>
  var grid = document.querySelector("#grid");

    var editor = Ned.create("#svg");
    editor.snapping = 10;
    //editor.singleInputs = true;
    //editor.singleOutputs = true;

    // only enable middle mouse button dragging
    editor.svg.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { 
        if (e.button !== 1) e.stopImmediatePropagation(); 
    });

    editor.panZoom = svgPanZoom(editor.svg, {
        viewportSelector: ".svg-pan-zoom_viewport", 
        panEnabled: true, 
        controlIconsEnabled: true, 
        zoomEnabled: true, 
        dblClickZoomEnabled: false, 
        mouseWheelZoomEnabled: true, 
        preventMouseEventsDefault: false, 
        zoomScaleSensitivity: 0.2, 
        minZoom: 0.5, 
        maxZoom: 2, 
        fit: false, 
        contain: false, 
        center: false, 
        refreshRate: "auto",
        onPan: function(newPan) {
            var zoom = this.getZoom();
            grid.setAttribute("x", -newPan.x / zoom);
            grid.setAttribute("y", -newPan.y / zoom);
        }
    });

    editor.screenToWorld = function(pos) {
        var rect = this.svg.getBoundingClientRect();
        var pan = this.panZoom.getPan();
        var zoom = this.panZoom.getZoom();

        return { 
            x: (((pos.x - rect.left) - pan.x) / zoom), 
            y: (((pos.y - rect.top) - pan.y) / zoom)
        };
    };

    window.addEventListener("resize", (e) => {
        editor.panZoom.resize();
    }, true);



    // after setup create nodes     
    var n1 = editor.createNode("Test node");
    n1.position = { x: 400, y: 280};
    n1.size = { width: 180, height: 90 };

    var n1i1 = n1.addInput("");
    var n1i2 = n1.addInput("Input B");

    var n1o1 = n1.addOutput("Output A");
    var n1o2 = n1.addOutput("Output B");

    var n2 = editor.createNode("Start");
    n2.position = { x: 100, y: 150};
    n2.size = { width: 100, height: 60 };
    var n2o1 = n2.addOutput("Output");

    n2o1.connectTo(n1i2);

    var n3 = editor.createNode("Other test");
    n3.position = { x: 200, y: 10};
    n3.size = { width: 180, height: 60 };
    var n3i1 = n3.addInput("Input B");
    var n3o1 = n3.addOutput("Output");

   </script>
```

this is a part of the js file:

```
   init(ned, sTitle) {
    this.editor = ned;
    this.inputs = [];
    this.outputs = [];

    // ****************** root ******************
    this.eRoot = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "svg");
    this.eRoot.setAttribute("class", "NodeContainer");
    var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('.NodeContainer');

    // Set their ids
    for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++){
        abcElements[i].id = i;

    }

    this.eRoot.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
    this.editor.nodegroup.appendChild(this.eRoot);

    // ****************** background ******************
    this.eBack = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "rect");
    this.eBack.setAttribute("class", "Background");
    this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eBack);

    // ****************** header ******************
    this.eHeader = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "g");
    this.eHeader.setAttribute("class", "Header");
    this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eHeader);

    this.eHeaderBack = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "rect");
    this.eHeader.appendChild(this.eHeaderBack);

    this.eHeaderText = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "text");
    this.eHeaderText.appendChild(document.createTextNode(sTitle));
    this.eHeaderText.setAttribute("x", "50%");
    this.eHeader.appendChild(this.eHeaderText);

    // ****************** inputs and outputs ******************
    this.eInputs = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "svg");
    this.eInputs.setAttribute("class", "Inputs");
    this.eInputs.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
    this.eInputs.setAttribute("x", "0%");
    this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eInputs);

    this.eOutputs = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "svg");
    this.eOutputs.setAttribute("class", "Outputs");
    this.eOutputs.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
    this.eOutputs.setAttribute("x", "100%");
    this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eOutputs);

    // ****************** foreign object ******************
    this.eForeign = document.createElementNS(ned.svg.ns, "foreignObject");
    this.eRoot.appendChild(this.eForeign);

    // selection events
    this.eRoot.addEventListener("click", (e) => { this.onClicked(e); });
    this.eHeader.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { this.beginNodeDrag (e); });
},
```

Comment: Well you can copy the HTML code of the current DOM via your browser dev tools ... whether everything will still _work_ when you just take this and copy&paste it elsewhere, might be a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Just run your JavaScript in the browser, and once your HTML code is generated, hit `F12`(on firefox/chrome) or right click the page and then click "view source" (name of tab may change depending on the browser). Then you can just copy/paste your generated components into your editor.

What do you mean by "convert them to pure HTML" ? If the purpose of this JS script is to generate HTML, running it basically will converting it to pure HTML.

Comment: It worked, but now I have to work on the JS, because a lot of stuff is appearing but not working.

Comment: The existing elements "nodegroup" is doubled. The original ones still functional (dragging etc...) but the new ones are not. Do you think it's better to build my template in this SVG? I am already trying to, I added a new "ul" seems like the browser is detecting it in the "inspect" but it doesn't appear.

Comment: this.ul = document.createElementNS(this.svg.ns,"ul");
  this.ul.setAttribute("class","rightmenu");
  this.ul.setAttribute("overflow", "visible");
  this.svg.appendChild(this.ul);

Comment: I never tried using SVG in JavaScript. If you want to use SVG, can't you use a software dedicated to that purpose ?